# Vertex Skinning Looks Messy on Real Android Device using Monodroid

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, opengl-es-2.0, glsles

I have no problem doing the "vertex skinning" for three-dimensional animation. All goes **well** when using the **emulator** (and genymotion). However, when run on a **real device** (such as Samsung and Lenovo) looks **messy**.

### Screenshoot (Emulator)

http://1drv.ms/1BzZ9Ib

[image]

### Screenshoot (Real device)

1drv.ms/1BzZ2we

[image]

### Passing skin transform matrix

```
int location = ...;
int arrayCount = ...;
float[] skinTransform = ...;
GL.UniformMatrix4(location, arrayCount, false, skinTransform);
```

### GLSL vertex

```
uniform mat4 World;
uniform mat4 View;
uniform mat4 Projection;
uniform mat4 Bones[20];

attribute vec4 Position;
attribute vec4 BoneIndices;
attribute vec4 BoneWeights;
attribute vec2 UV;
varying vec4 v_Position;
varying vec2 v_UV;

void main()
{
    mat4 skinTransform;
    int boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.x);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.x;
    boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.y);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.y;
    boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.z);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.z;
    boneIndex = int(BoneIndices.w);
    skinTransform += Bones[boneIndex] * BoneWeights.w;
    vec4 skinPos = Position * skinTransform;
    vec4 worldPosition = skinPos * World;
    vec4 viewPosition = worldPosition * View;
    v_Position = viewPosition * Projection;
    v_UV = UV;
    gl_Position = v_Position;
}
```

### APK

http://1drv.ms/1BzYV3Q
**Touch** screen to **on/off** animation.

### Info

1. Xamarin.Android = 4.10.x.x
2. Emulator Target = API 16 or 4.1
3. Real device Target = API 16 or 4.1
4. App Target = API 10 or 2.3 (tested also in API 14 and API 16), **results remain the same**

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

Best regards and thank you.